# Does this cause memory leak when I call the deconstructor?

Tags: c++

I have a data structures project I have to do for my Uni class which is to implement a stack with a linked list; simple stuff. We have had some help, code-wise, to show us the correct way to implement such a structure.

Stack class:

```
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(void)
    {
        top = NULL;     // Initialises defualt top node pointer.
    }

    ~Stack(void)
    {
        while (NodePop() != NULL){}
    }

    void Push(int value)    // Pushes a new node onto the stack.
    {
        Node* temp = new Node(value, top);  // Creates a temporary node with a value and makes it 
                                            // point to the top node as the next node in the stack.

        top = temp;                         // Temporary node becomes the top node in the stack.
    }

    Node* NodePop(void)
    {
        /* Remove top node from the stack */
        Node* temp = top;                       // Creates a temporary node to return, sets it to top node.
        if (top != NULL) top = top->getNext();  // Points the stacks top node to the next node in the list.
        return temp;                            // Returns a pointer to the popped node still in the heap.
    }

    int Pop(void)       // Pops the top node off of the stack. Returns the nodes value.
    {
        Node* temp = NodePop();     
        int valueReturn = 0;

        /* Sets the return value */
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            valueReturn = temp->getVal();   // Set return value to the nodes value if there is a node left.
        }
        else
        {
            throw "Stack Empty";            // Throws exception if temp is NULL and stack is empty. 
        }

        delete temp;            // Deletes the node entirely from the heap.

        return valueReturn;
    }

private:
    Node* top;

};
```

Node class:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(int value, Node* nextptr = NULL, Node* prevptr = NULL, int currentpriority = 0)
    {
        /* Set initial variables for the node at creation */
        this->value = value;
        this->next = nextptr;
        this->prev = prevptr;
        this->priority = currentpriority;
    }

    // bunch of getters and setters...

private:
    Node* next;     // Pointer to the next node.
    Node* prev;     // Pointer to the previous node.
    int priority;   // Stores the node priority as a number 0-9.
    int value;      // Stores the node value for printing.

};
```

We cannot change any of the classes structure (too my annoyance, NodePop() should be private, but w/e).

So here NodePop() essentially removes the top node from the list but doesn't delete it; it removes all reference to it from the linked list but it never deletes it from the heap, it's only deleted from the heap in Pop(). All good (except for being able to call NodePop() publicly, but again, I'm not allowed to make it private). But when I call the destructor is has to use NodePop(), not Pop().

**So does that mean the node is never deleted from the heap when NodePop() runs from the destructor?**

**If so how would I delete them because it's going to run nodePop() if i have it in a while, do-while, or if statement condition so there will always be one node left undeleted?**

Comment: There are so many things wrong with the code you've been given, what's a memory leak or a thousand?

Comment: Quite, it's a shame that's been given at a university as an example of C++. Stroustrup mentions this problem a lot in his keynotes, instructors teaching bad C as an introduction to C++.

Comment: I'm going to be charitable to myself and you and say write them a note and ask if this was meant to call Pop and not NodePop because otherwise this would leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the nodes are not deleted, and this code will leak. You can verify that by using a tool like Valgrind.

I would change the `while` to something like `while (Node *N = NodePop()) delete N;`

FYI, this code is definitely not idiomatic C++11. It's basically poorly written C, and I'd expect to find more bugs in it. Your teacher should get a slap on the wrist for presenting C++11 like this :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had no idea you could create variables inside a while loop condition, but I'm still new to programming.

Comment: No worries. I can recommend this book for new C++ programmers: http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html -- made by the inventor of C++, and it covers modern C++ design.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code in question

```
~Stack(void)
{
    while (NodePop() != NULL){}
}

Node* NodePop(void)
{
    /* Remove top node from the stack */
    Node* temp = top;                       // Creates a temporary node to return, sets it to top node.
    if (top != NULL) top = top->getNext();  // Points the stacks top node to the next node in the list.
    return temp;                            // Returns a pointer to the popped node still in the heap.
}
```

Your destructor calls NodePop() until that function returns NULL.  Let's look at what NodePop() does.  The comment in the code claims that it `Creates a temporary node to return`  That is not true.  It creates a pointer to a Node (a Node*) and sets that pointer to point the same place that `top` does.  If `top` is not null, it sets `top` to point to top's next node.  It the returns `temp`, which *is a pointer to what was originally the top Node*.

At no point to you release memory associated with any Node, so yes there is a memory leak.

You can fix the leak by deleting each Node* that you encounter in the destructor that is not NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The comments in my code are awful, I still need to re-do a few of them before I'm finished, I understand that it's a pointer.